# JQPLOT - How to use breakpoints

Tags: jqplot, breakpoints

I am trying to implement a horizontal bar graph using jqplot library. 
In my case, some of the bars of the graph might show extraordinary spike so for example if the 3 bars of my graph have data value of 150(max), the spiked bar might have a data value of 1000.

To accomodate this requirement, I went through the documentation of jqplot and found out that they have something called "breakpoint" to break the axes at some particular place. 
[http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-linearAxisRenderer-js.html#$.jqplot.LinearAxisRenderer.breakPoints](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-linearAxisRenderer-js.html#%24.jqplot.LinearAxisRenderer.breakPoints)

Now suppose my data for the series looks like this : 
[100, 150, 50, 250, 1200, 100]

How in the above case can i make sure that jqplot inserts a breakpoint after 250 and continues the axes ticks at 1200?

[Edited] Ok, so after using the below code I am able to get the breakpoints working:
chart.axes.xaxis.breakPoints=[10,100];
chart.replot();
(i also went through the jqplot source and found out that for breakpoints to work, we need to manually set the ticks, which I did)

But my original problem is still at large!
Suppose my series looks like 
[100, 200, 300, 20000]
In this case, even if I use breakpoints, my 3 bars which are of considerably lesser weight seems very tiny as compared to the 4th bar (20000 weight)
this makes the graph unreadable. 
Can some one please suggest a way out of this?

Comment: please edit to include the code that you've tried so far

Answer (score 0):

"How to implement breakpoints": A replot of data as mentioned above, is not the right way to use breakpoints:

> `chart.axes.xaxis.breakPoints=[10,100]; chart.replot();`

Hava a look on that piece of code, I solved the breakpoint issue:
Having all data values of my barchart < 200 exept of one bar value > 850 i would like to set a breakpoint between 250 and 850.

And here it's how this can be done:

```
      axes: {
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                ticks: ticks
            },
    yaxis: {
        ticks: [0,50,100,150,200,250,275,825,850,900,950],
        tickOptions: {
        formatString: '%.0d'
        },
        renderer: $.jqplot.LinearAxisRenderer,
        rendererOptions: {
            breakPoints: [275,825],
            breakTickLabel: "&asymp;",
            forceTickAt0: true
                     }
        }
```

Important:

- Use the LinearAxisRenderer.
- add your ticks manually in an array.
- set the breakpoint with the rendererOptions.
- The Array with the ticks, HAS TO CONTAIN the values, which you like to set the breakpoints in the rendererOptions.

Regards 
Matthias

P.S.: I also have a picture of the graph, but you don't allow me to post images until I get 10 reputations.